# How to center print head after Marlin upgrade?

Tags: troubleshooting, tronxy-xy-2-pro

Flashed Marlin to my Tronxy XY-2 Pro but two things are happening:

1. I tried printing a rook but the print got shoved to the front left corner.
2. X is way off to the right when it homes.

The computer homes the project to the center of the print bed  but when push comes to shove #1 happens.

Is their anyway I can get the machine to start printing in the middle of the bed.

Using Cura slicer.

Comment: This can be caused by either incorrect slicer settings (origin at center is notorious using Cura) or ["How to center my prints on the build platform? (Re-calibrate homing offset)"](/q/6375). If firmware related this question is a duplicate, please check your slicer settings first. Please provide additional information on Cura printer settings and possibly an image of sliced rook, and printed rook. Which firmware did you install, pre-compiled or self-configured?

Comment: Thanks for the additions you added, but it still isn't enough to answer the question. Can you add a screenshot of the "Machine settings" window (showing the tab sheet called "Printer").